# Best/Fastest Way To Change/Access Elements of a Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, matrix

I'm quite new to C# and I'm having difficult with our arrays, arrays of arrays, jagged arrays, matrixes and stuff. It's quite different from the C++ , since I can't get a reference (unless I use unsafe code) to a row of a matrix, using pointers and stuff.

Anyway, here's the problem: I have a struct/class called "Image" that cointains 1024 columns and 768 lines. For each line/column theres a 'pixel' struct/class that contains 3 bytes. I'd like to get/set pixels in random places of the matrix as fast as possible.

Let's pretend I have a matrix with 25 pixels. That is 5 rows and 5 columns, something like this:

```
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P Q R S T 
U V X W Y
```

And I need to compare M to H and R. Then M to L and N. Then I need to 'sum' G+H+I+L+M+N+Q+R+S.

How can I do that?

Possibilities:
1) Create something like pixel[5][5] (that's a jagged array, right?), which will be slow whenever I try to compare elements on different columns, right?
2) Create something like pixel[25] , which won't be as easy to code/ready because I'll need to do some (simple) math each and everything I want to access a element
3) Create something like pixe[5,5] (that's a multi-dimensional array, right?)... But I don't know how that will be translated to actual memory... If it's going to be a single block of memory, like the pixe[25], or what...

Since I intend to do this operations ('random' sums/comparison of elements that are in different rows/columns) tens of thousands of times per image. And I have 1000+ imagens. Code optimization is a must... Sadly I'm not sure which structure / classe I should use.

**TL;DR: Whats the FASTEST and whats the EASIEST (coding wise) way of getting/setting elements in random positions of a (fixed size) matrix?**

edit: I do not want to compare C++ to C#. I'm just saying I AM NEW TO C# and I'd like to find the best way to accomplish this, using C#. Please don't tell me to go back to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished testing, heres the result:

```
SD Array Test1: 00:00:00.9388379
SD Array Test2: 00:00:00.4117926
MD Array Test1: 00:00:01.4977765
MD Array Test2: 00:00:00.8950093
Jagged Array Test1: 00:00:03.6850013
Jagged Array Test2: 00:00:00.5036041
```

Conclusion: Single dimensional array is the way to go... Sadly we lose in readability.

And heres the code:

```
    int[] myArray = new int[10000 * 10000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            myArray[(i*10000)+j] = i+j;
        }
    }



    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    int sum = 0;

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += myArray[(j * 10000) + i];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("SD Array Test1: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    sum=0;

    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += myArray[(i * 10000) + j];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("SD Array Test2: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());

    myArray = null;

    int[,] MDA = new int[10000, 10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            MDA[i, j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += MDA[j, i];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("MD Array Test1: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());

    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += MDA[i, j];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("MD Array Test2: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    MDA = null;

    int[][] JA = new int[10000][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        JA[i] = new int[10000];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            JA[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += JA[j][i];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Jagged Array Test1: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());

    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            sum += JA[i][j];
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Jagged Array Test2: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    MDA = null;

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: There's a big difference between random access and sequential one.

Comment: It is best to put the stopwatch results into local variables, then spit them all out in the end. The WriteLine calls can interfere with timing.

Comment: To gain the bounds checking optimization: for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; ++i) { ...foo[i]... }

Comment: I always reset the StopWatch  before the loop and after the writelines. But using array.Length is really ellegant and imporant. As technique / feature I'm not yet used too. "Voted up" for remembering me about this features. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on pixel based image processing in C#. I found that pattern #2 in your list is fastest. For speed, you must forget about accessing pixels via some kind of nice abstract interface. The pixel processing routines must explicitly deal with the width and height of the image. This makes for crappy code in general, but unless Microsoft improves the C# compiler, we are stuck with this approach.

If your for loops start at index 0 of an array, and end at array.Length - 1, the compiler will optimize out the array index bounds testing. This is nice, but typically you have to use more than one pixel at a time while processing.