# Overloading Operator[] For Single Dimension Array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, operator-overloading

To solve a problem I already asked here [Best/Fastest Way To Change/Access Elements of a Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369479/best-fastest-way-to-change-access-elements-of-a-matrix)

I'm using single dimension arrays to store matrixes. But accessing elements of the matrix becomes a cumbersome task.

I'm currently storing my matrixes in arrays like this

```
type[numberOfRows * numberOfColumns] myArray;
```

And to access the `[n][m]` element I have to type this

```
blargh = myArray[(n*numberOfRows)+m];
```

... I'm wondering if its possible to overload / create new operators `[][]` that would 'translate' `myArray[n][m]` to `myArray[(n*numberOfRows)+m]`. And IF that IS possible, would that hinder the performance too much.

edit: turns out a 'forced-inline' method yields a performance gain.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]public void set(int x, int y, T value)
    {
        array[(x * wid) + y] = value;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]public T get(int x, int y)
    {
        return array[(x*wid) + y];
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of [jagged arrays and multi-dimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)? One of those might be what you're really looking for.

Comment: Random access in multi-dimensional arrays and sequencial access of columns on jagged arrays are too slow.

Comment: I'd expect both of those to be extremely fast. Maybe confusing to work with in certain ways, but the actual random/sequential access would be fast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370466/1642116

This simple code compares the access of elements, sequentially. First going by columns and then by rows. You can see there's a huge difference if you use single-dimensional arrays and jagged arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to overload the operator for the array type, or change its definition; that can only be done from the definition of that type, which you can't control.

What you *can* do is create your own type that wraps the array, and that overloads the operators that you want:

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private T[] array;

    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return array[row + column]; }
    }
}
```

Whether or not the performance difference (which should be small, but not nothing) are an issue for your program is something that you're going to need to profile and measure.

Comment: I like this approach. As soon as  I get home I'll test it.

Comment: I just tested, and usign a forced-inline method yields a performance gain over properties. Check my edit.

Comment: @Trauer Are you compiling in debug mode, or without optimizations?

Comment: @Trauer It will influence the ability of methods to be inlined.  The added debugging information can quite often prohibit inlining, and the inliners in general are going to be much less aggressive when in debug mode, or when a debugger is attached, to allow the behavior to be more clearly observed by the developer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement double indexing (i.e. `matrix[r][c]` syntax) would be using a [*Proxy Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) (also known as the *Surrogate Pattern*).

The idea is to overload the top-level `operator[]` to return a special object that "remembers" the first index and the array, and provides its own overload of the `operator[]` that combines the "remembered" first-level index with the supplied second-level index to produce the actual "flat" index into the data array.

In terms of the program logic, the proxy object represents the column of your matrix. Here is how you can implement this:

```
public class Matrix<T> {
    private readonly T[] data;
    private readonly int rowCount;
    public class Column {
        private readonly Matrix<T> m;
        private readonly int r;
        internal Column(Matrix<T> m, int r) {
            this.m = m;
            this.r = r;
        }
        public T this[int c] {
            get {
                return m.data[m.rowCount*r + c];
            }
        }
    }
    public Column this[int r] {
        get {
            return new Column(this, r);
        }
    }
}
```

The performance implications of this approach is that there would be an object created each time that you access the top level matrix.